# What controls the encoding of GET and POST variables?

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, get

I've done some tests, and it appears that when I test this:

`http://127.0.0.1/test.php?x={some non-english string}`

`http://127.0.0.1/test.php?x=الapple`

By examining the output of:

```
echo bin2hex($_GET["x"]);
```

- In `Firefox` & `Chrome`, I get the UTF-8 representation of the string `d8a7d9846170706c65`.
- `$_GET['x']` variable. In `IE`, I get `3f3f6170706c65`. which is wrong

And I know that PHP does not change encoding, and only sees the string as a byte array.

The question is:

Is this controlled by the browser used?

Is it reliable to always assume the input it in UTF-8 encoding?

**Is there a way to manage what encoding the browser sends to the server? across all browsers?**

Comment: I would say it depends on how you set your charset in the meta of your HTML page. Did not test it though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference from where the request originated.

If it’s from a user’s input, e.g., entering the URL into the browser’s address field, most browsers follow the [suggestion in RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) and use UTF-8 as encoding:

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual
> data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS],
> the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8
> character encoding [STD63]; […]

Although this is intended for new URI schemes and HTTP is quite old.

However, if the URL was embedded in a document, e.g., as a link or form action, the document’s encoding is used unless the data was already encoded using the URL encoding. And in case the data has a wrong encoding, invalid sequences may be replaces with certain characters that should denote those invalid sequences like the `�` (U+FFFD) in Unicode does. Similarly, the invalid encoded characters `ل` and `ا` may have been replaces by `?`, which has the code point 0x3F in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should come down to how `urldecode` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) interprets it, since the `$_GET` variables are all passed through that function (see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

**EDIT**

To encode the characters to UTF-8 for use in a URL from the client side, you can use the `encodeURI` in JavaScript.

For the example you gave, you can do `encodeURI('الapple');`, which should return `"%D8%A7%D9%84apple"`

Giving this to PHP's `urldecode` function (as it would be automatically) returns the original string, with the following hex output;

```
echo bin2hex(urldecode("%D8%A7%D9%84apple")); //outputs d8a7d9846170706c65
```

Comment: nop, edited the question with more information, showing why this won't work.

Comment: Cheers for the boilerplate comment, saying this "won't work" doesn't make any sense, I'm simply telling you what PHP's behaviour is, as per your original question.

Comment: sorry if my comment offended you, `urldecode` is it not needed when dealing with GET variables, since they are automatically decoded, and I showed the actual byte array (`bin2hex`) output, in different browsers.

Comment: Really? Are `$_GET` variables automatically passed through `urldecode` to decode them? Don't worry, I'm not offended :D I just don't want to waste my time on changing questions and OP's who don't read answers :P

Comment: Yes, If you type in a url like this: `file.php?x=%61%62` the result will be that `$_GET['x']` has the value of `'ap'` without requiring any extra url decode.

Comment: Yeah.. I know.. in fact, I stated that in my answer. Can't tell if I'm being trolled right now..

Comment: No trolling, I thought you meant that I would need to re-do urldecode some how, which isnt possible,  -- considering that different browsers give different results (as i edited in my question), anything done on the server side is irrelevant, I am looking for client side fix.

Comment: Fair enough, have updated answer to try and give a solution. For future reference, we're not paid to answer questions - some gratitude goes a long way (rather than a generic comment which gives the impression that you haven't even read the provided answer).

Answer (score -1):

yes it's possible !

To encode the URL :

```
<?php
   $url = "http://127.0.0.1/test.php?x=".urlencode("some non-english string");
?>
```

To decode the URL :

```
<?php
   $url = urldecode($_GET["x"]);
?>
```

Comment: nop, edited the question with more information, showing why this won't work.